# How can I scale a set of 2D arrays (3D array) by a 2D array in a vectorized way using NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have a 3D matrix containing N x N covariance matrices for M channels [M x N x N]. I also have a 2D matrix of scaling factors for each channel at a series of time points [M x T]. I want to produce a 4D matrix containing a scaled version of the relevant channel's covariance at each time point. So to be clear, [M x T] * [M x N x N] -> [M x T x N x N]

Current version using for loops:

```
m, t, n = 4, 10, 7
channel_timeseries = np.zeros((m, t))
covariances = np.random.rand(m, n, n)

result_array = np.zeros((m, t, n, n))

# Each channel
for i, (channel_cov, channel_timeseries) in enumerate(zip(covariances, channel_timeseries)):
    # Each time point
    for j, time_point in enumerate(channel_timeseries):
        result_array[i, j] = time_point * channel_cov
```

This should lead to the result array being all zeros. Replacing the initialisation of the channel_timeseries with `np.ones`, we should see the covariance for each channel replicated unchanged at every step of the time series.

The case which actually matters to me is one in which every channel has a scalar value at every time point and we scale the covariance matrix for the relevant channel by the value matching the correct channel and time point.

As you can see above, I can do this with a for loop and it works completely fine, but I'm working with some huge datasets and it would be better to have a vectorised solution.

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.einsum`, [as b-fg said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61303066/636626)

```
np.einsum('mt,mno->mtno', channel_timeseries, covariances)
```

or Broadcasting:

```
channel_timeseries[:, :, None, None] * covariances[:, None, :, :]
```

Comment: I was interested to see that the broadcasting approach was faster than einsum (einsum: 3.82 ms ± 44.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each) broadcasting: 2.13 ms ± 7.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each) ) so I'm going with that solution. Thanks very much!

Comment: Yes, that's often (but not always) the case.

Answer (score 1):

[`numpy.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) will come handy here. I have modified your code with a random `channel_timeseries` array, increased the arrays size, and renamed the loop variables (otherwise you overwrite the original ones!)

```
import numpy as np
import time

m, t, n = 40, 100, 70
channel_timeseries = np.random.rand(m, t)
covariances = np.random.rand(m, n, n)

t0 = time.time()
result_array_1 = np.zeros((m, t, n, n))
# Each channel
for i, (c_cov, c_ts) in enumerate(zip(covariances, channel_timeseries)):
    # Each time point
    for j, time_point in enumerate(c_ts):
        result_array_1[i, j] = time_point * c_cov
t1 = time.time()
result_array_2 = np.einsum('ij,ikl->ijkl', channel_timeseries, covariances)
t2 = time.time()

print(np.array_equal(result_array_1, result_array_2)) # True
print('Time for result_array_1: ', t1-t0) # 0.07601261138916016
print('Time for result_array_2: ', t2-t1) # 0.02957916259765625
```

This results in a speed increase of more than 50% with `numpy.einsum` in my machine.

Comment: Thanks for this! I accepted Nils' answer because he also suggested the broadcasting approach which turns out to be a little faster again.

for loop: 142 ms ± 491 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

einsum: 3.82 ms ± 44.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
broadcasting: 2.13 ms ± 7.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)